# Rolling 2 dice probability

Tags: probability

**Question:** Sarah rolls a standard $6$-sided die twice. What is the probability of rolling integers that differ by $2$ on her first two rolls?

**What I have tried:**  I found the total number of rolls by multiplying 6*6 to get 36 total rolls, but I don't know how to continue from here. I am a beginner in Counting/Probability, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You just need to count the number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with $a,b\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that $|a-b|=2$.  This should not be a hard calculation, though perhaps it's a bit too hard to do mentally.

Comment: Thank you @lulu, can you put that as an answer so I can accept it? I really am new to Probability, this is my first week in Probability at school.

Comment: I suggest:  Once you have done that count, post your own solution.  I will then check it for you.

Comment: Can you check my solution @lulu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: For each outcome of the first roll (1,...,6), see which rolls you need for the second throw in order to satisfy the statement. Then count them up and divide by the total number of possible rolls you already found. (Note that "differ by 2" can be in either direction - higher or lower!)

Answer (score 2):

I found all the numbers such that $(a,b)$ are in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$ and that $\vert a-b \vert=2$. I listed all the pairs such that $a-b=2$, the unordered pairs, but there can be $8$ ordered pairs because you can switch $a$ and $b$.

These are the unordered pairs:
$(3, 1)
(4, 2)
(5, 3)
(6, 4)$

$4$(unordered pairs)$\cdot 2$(for ordering them)$/36$(total pairs)=$4 \cdot 2/36=8/36$=$\boxed{2/9}$

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  It's a bit hard to read though...you should indicate clearly that there are $4$ unordered pairs that work, hence $8$ ordered pairs.  But your math is correct (+1).

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful!

Comment: I made it a bit easier to read now, thanks @lulu

Answer (score 1):

Because sometimes a picture can be worth a few equations (better than a thousand words, perhaps), here's a graphical depiction of the probabilities you're combining.

[image]